# html: Correctly add a definition for a var tag.

Tags: html, var

I have this piece of code.

```
<cite>Einstien</cite> calculated that <var>E</var>=<var>m</var><var>c</var><sup>2</sup>
```

but it feels incomplete.

Whilst the `var` tag is semantically correct, it has no way of telling a user what the var represents 
 for example E = energy

would it therefore be correct to use a `title` or `cite` attribute to define what the var represents
something like `<var title="energy">E</var>` or `<var cite="energy">E</var>`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `title` attribute.

According to the W3C, the `title` attribute applies to the `var` element via the global set of attributes (sources: [var Element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/var), [HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-var-element)).

Comment: Ah forgot to check W3C thanks for the info,  I only checked Mozilla and a couple of others.